# Knockout Js:- Label bind with delete button

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

I use below code, this code is working fine.

But i want to need when label check, label bind with delete button and also when click on delete, value uncheck.

How it's possible for this code?

```
<div id="current-selected" style="" data-bind="text: selectedChoicesDelimited">
    <a href="" id="clearAll" >Clear All</a>                     
</div>
<div data-role="content" class="filter-options-content" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
    <ol class="items mcs-items" data-bind="foreach: choices">
        <li>
            <label>
                <input id="5" class="multifilter" value="attribute?activity?5" type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: $parent.selectedChoices" ><span data-bind="text: $data"><input type="button" value="Remove Task" data-bind="click: $parent.removeChoices"></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {};

    viewModel.choices = ["Outdoor", "Recreation", "Gym"];
    viewModel.selectedChoices = ko.observableArray([]);

    viewModel.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.selectedChoices().join(",");
    });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

Below in image, output for this code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7o8p.png)

Below image, i want to need. When click on [x], value uncheck.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKGYx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me explain, whenever you use `text` binding what it does, it actually displays the text value of your parameter that you are passing to the associated DOM element. In fact, knockout sets the element’s content to a `text node` with your parameter. Any nested elements content will be overwritten. I see in your code you have a child DOM element inside your `text-binding`.

```
<div id="current-selected" style="" data-bind="text: selectedChoicesDelimited">
   <!-- this content will be overwritten by value of a your parameter -->
   <a href="" id="clearAll" >Clear All</a>                     
</div>
```

Or again here

```
<span data-bind="text: $data">
   <!-- this content will be overwritten by value of a your parameter -->
   <input type="button" value="Remove Task" data-bind="click: $parent.removeChoices">
</span>
```

Here what I would do to implement what you are looking for.

Working Example : https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/80/

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <!-- ko foreach: selectedChoices -->
  <li>
   <div>
     <span data-bind="ifnot:$index() === 0">,</span>
     <span data-bind="text:$data"></span> 
     <span data-bind="click:$parent.removeSelectedItem" class="remove">[x] </span>
   </div>
  </li>
   <!-- /ko -->
  <li>
     <a href="" id="clearAll" data-bind="click:removeAllSelectedItem ,visible:selectedChoices().length > 1" >Clear All</a>    
  </li>
</ul>


<div data-role="content" class="filter-options-content" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
    <ol class="items mcs-items" data-bind="foreach: choices">
        <li>
            <label>
                <input id="5" class="multifilter" value="attribute?activity?5" type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: $parent.selectedChoices" ><span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = {};
    viewModel.choices = ["Outdoor", "Recreation", "Gym"];
    viewModel.selectedChoices = ko.observableArray([]);
    viewModel.removeSelectedItem = function(data){
         ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.selectedChoices(), function (item) {
          if (item === data)return viewModel.selectedChoices.remove(item);
        });
    }
    viewModel.removeAllSelectedItem = function(data){
      viewModel.selectedChoices([]);
    }
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```